# Why do I receive an "Object does not support autocomplete jquery method" runtime error when implementing my autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, runtime-error

I have realised that for my autocomplete I don't really need to work with an ajax call(I have seen many examples that worked with ajax call), I can simply work with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(getProjects());
    $("#inputSearchProject.ClientID").autocomplete(myData);
});
```

Where, `getProjects()` is a small script and `TheProjects` is a property that it is initialized with the suggestion JSON string for my autocomplete.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getProjects() {
        return '<%= this.TheProjects %>';
    }
</script>
```

When debugging I have noticed that myData receives the values, but I still get an runtime error : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'" - even though I have searched, I haven't found the answer to this.

EDIT: I have solved the error (it was a silly one:) novice kind of mistake)

I have changed my code into:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(getProjects());
     $("[id$='txtSearchProject']").keypress(function () 
   {
     $("[id$='txtSearchProject']").autocomplete(myData);
  })
 });
```

because I want autocomplete to be started only when it detects I have written something in the input control. Do you have any suggestions why it doesn't work?

---

Thank you all for your suggestions. I have solved my problem, but only with the tips I have received from you. I am going to put here my small piece of code, maybe someone with a similar question will find it useful in the future:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(getProjects());
 $("[id$='txtSearchProject']").keypress(function () 
  {
       $("[id$='txtSearchProject']").autocomplete({ source: myData});
  })
});
```

//I have added instead of .autocomplete(my data) --->.autocomplete({ source: myData})

Comment: Based on your source, I'd guess that you're attempting to use the jQueryUI plugin for autocomplete. Are you sure that the source for jqueryUI is included at the top of the page after your jQuery include?

Comment: Now I have in my asp file the following scripts included:  <script src="Scripts/ProjectManagementPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script> (here is the small code I have previously showed to you)
    <script src="Scripts/A1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/A2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> (and the other 2 are the source for jqueryUI.

Comment: The scripts have to be in the right order. The first script include should be your jQuery script include. The second should be jQueryUI. All other scripts should come after these.

Comment: You were right, that actually solved my error, thank you. But the autocomplete it's still not working. Do you have any suggestion ? :)

Comment: I'd need more information to suggest why autocomplete does not behave, but my first guess would be that either your data is malformed or there is some other error preventing the autocomplete method from executing. If you're using Firebug or Chrome, you should be able to look at the console log to get a better defined error.

Comment: LE: Even with all the changes I have made, the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" appears after typing 2 characters in my input control (I assume it needs at least 2 characters to fire the autocomplete and there is when the problem occurs). Sorry for asking so many questions and thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the jQuery UI script file.

Get it here:

http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: I have just added the 2 .js scripts from your link (by the way, thank you:) ), but it's still the same. My inputSearchProject - it's a html input. should I change the control ?  I am sorry for theese questions but it's my first time to work with jquery :)

Comment: @Cropcircles See Joel's comment about script order.